# Alias custom domain to GitHub repository for git clone

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, git, alias

What I'm trying to do is setup a custom domain name so that it can be cloned as a git repository using `git clone`.
For example,

```bash
$ git clone https://my-domain-name.tld/ # would be cloned into my-domain-name.tld
# and
$ git clone https://my-domain-name.tld/my-repository # would be cloned into my-repository
```

I don't actually want to host the repository itself on my server, I just want to configure the DNS (hopefully that's all that's required) so that it will point any requests `git clone` makes to GitHub, where the repositories in question are actually hosted.

I'm not sure if `git clone https://my-domain-name.tld/` without anything after that (so no path in the URL) would work, but since `git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repo>` works I figured it must at least be possible for `git clone https://not-github.com/<repo>` to work.

Comment: not sure it possible via dns only, theoretically you can achieve that via reverse proxy , but you still need some VPS as middleware. You can configure nginx or any other reverse proxy there.